# Refresh the DataGrid row by row when observablecollection is added during the loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

There is a DataGrid in the windows and it's binding to a ObservableCollection nd there is a command to adding a list of item to the collection.
I hope the DataGrid could adding a row one by one during the loop, but now it will add a batch of items to the DataGrid when the command is done.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InfoList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Path=Field1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding Path=Field2}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

public class XXViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Info> infoList = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
    public ObservableCollection<Info> InfoList
    {
        get{return infoList;}           
    }

    private void XXCommand()
    {    
        List<Info> list = this.GetList();
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            // the datagrid won't update or show this item immediately          
            this.InfoList.Add(item);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your add code onto the `Dispatcher`'s queue:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate
{
    InfoList.Add(item);
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan, thanks for your answer. Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher doesn't work, but it works by currentWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke function.

Comment: @Carlos Would you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

There might be several Problems which we cannot identify from your code:

1. Did you set your DataContext of the view so that your collection can
   be found at runtime?
2. Does your collection type contains the given fields for table
   column?
3. Did you initialize your view model in the ui thread or another?

I tend to point 1 being a popular issue.

Comment: Hi, Jan thanks you answer. I have bind the viewmodel instance as window DataContext in xaml code, and the the column binding field/proerty is exits in the Info class. The main issue is how to refresh datagrid when adding a row to ObservableCollection.